# Python SQLite3 Retrieve Variables From SELECT Query

Tags: python, sql, variables

I'm busy writting a python script that is querying two db tables to build a single row of data per row it finds. Here is my script at the moment

```
#========================================================================
# DB CONNECT FUNCTION
#========================================================================
def f_connect(status):

    global gv_conn
    global gv_curs

    if status == 1:
        gv_conn = sqlite3.connect("./data.db")
        gv_curs = gv_conn.cursor()
    else
        gv_conn.close()

#========================================================================
# PREPARE SQL STATEMENTS
#========================================================================
def f_statements():

    global users_stmt
    users_stmt = ("select * from users")
    global users_curs
    users_curs = gv_conn.cursor()

    global uinfo_stmt
    uinfo_stmt = ("select * from uinfo" +
                  "where ui_u_id = ?")
    global uinfo_curs
    uinfo_curs = gv_conn.cursor()

#========================================================================
#
# MAIN SCRIPT START
#
#========================================================================

f_connect(1)

f_statements()

la_users = []

for u_row in users_curs.execute(users_stmt):

    # THIS LINE GETS USERS FROM THE ABOVE STATEMENT
    # AND ADDS THEM TO THE DICTIONARY
    la_users.append({"u_id": u_row[0], "u_name": u_row[1]})

    # THIS LINE EXECUTES ANOTHER QUERY TO RETRIEVE
    # A SINGLE ROW OF DATA FROM ANOTHER TABLE
    la_uinfo = uinfo_curs.execute(uinfo_stmt, "1")

f_connect(0)
```

My problem is that when I execute the first sql statement I can get get the data by looping using a for loop which is storing the data so i can access it using u_row[int].

When I execute the second query it is storing it inside la_uinfo although when I try to get the data from la_uinfo[int] it doesn't work? How can I retrieve the data from my second query without using another for loop? (I shouldn't have to considering it only returns one row)

Answer (score 0):

Cursors are not indexable, so  `cursor[0]` will not work. To retrieve the first row of a cursor, you should use `cursor.fetchone()`.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve a row without a cursor? Like execute into an array? The second statement only returns one row so i dont see why i would need a cursor

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like python always executes sql with cursors

Comment: Yes, Python always executes queries with cursors. `uinfo_curs.execute(uinfo_stmt, "1")` returns a cursor. So, for example, you can use `uinfo_curs.execute(uinfo_stmt, "1").fetchone()` to execute the query and fetch the first row.